# React Google Recaptcha

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Using the React Google Recaptcha npm package(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha), this works pretty well to get the captcha on the screen.

I'm wondering if there is a way to get this captcha unactionable/disabled? The goal is to enable it only if certain criteria matches.

Please share some tips/suggestions. Thank you!

Here is the code fragment:

```
 import Recaptcha from "react-google-recaptcha";
 <Recaptcha sitekey='#' onChange={enableStuff} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't disable interaction with the reCAPTCHA widget once it has been rendered.

What you can do is render the widget when certain criteria match. For example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ready: false
    }
  }
  
  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ ready: e.target.checked });
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.onChange} />
        {this.state.ready && 
          <Reaptcha sitekey="YOUR_KEY" onVerify={() => {}} />
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.1/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/reaptcha@1.1.0-beta.1"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

The library used was https://github.com/sarneeh/reaptcha